# MongoDB BsonDocument to DataTable and vice versa

Tags: c#, mongodb, datatable

For some reason, I would like to store a ADO.NET `DataTable` inside a `BsonDocument`, but I am surprised that the official C# driver (2.0) refuses to serialize `DataTable` as array of `BsonDocument`s. I know it is fairly easy to write your own method to do so, but this could be done in pretty generic fashion. Also, the opposite direction is pretty straightforward (however since MongoDB is schemaless it could generate a lot of `NULL`s).

Am I missing something in the default driver that would allow such serialization, or I must write some boring boilerplate code (which, I could reuse later, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
public async Task SaveDataTableToCollection(DataTable dt)
      {
          var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoConnection"];
          var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
          var database = client.GetDatabase("myMongoDatabaseName");

          var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");

          List<BsonDocument> batch = new List<BsonDocument>();
          foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
              var dictionary = dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => dr[col.ColumnName]);
              batch.Add(new BsonDocument(dictionary));
          }

          await collection.InsertManyAsync(batch.AsEnumerable());
      }
```